# main" java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using ':99' as the value of the DISPLAY variable

Tags: x11, display

I am using webswing and I'm getting below error . I have tried almost all the workaround suggested in the google like setting Display , installating library xauth , tried with ssh -x , started server with  Djava.awt.headless=true ,5.   /etc/ssh/sshd_config
               X11Forwarding yes

1. Downloaded xorg-x11-xauth through yum
2. Set the display variable manually 
   export DISPLAY=:0.0 
   export DISPLAY=:0.0
3. Login through –x option ssh -X user@ip_address
4. Set the JAVA_OPTIONS in the start.sh script under WEBSWING folder
   Djava.awt.headless=true
5. /etc/ssh/sshd_config
              X11Forwarding yes
6. Login with the root and restarted the webswing

nothing worked for me , any suggestions welcome

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the xvfb service is installed and running.

You can check example [Dockerfile](https://bitbucket.org/meszarv/webswing/src/master/webswing-assembly/src/main/docker/Dockerfile)  for additional help